# finding the sum of two integers in array that match an element in another array

Tags: python

The function takes two arrays arr1 and arr2 return true of any two integers in arr1 sums up to any element in arr2.I tried to do it but it's giving me a runtime error.

arr1[-1,8,3]

arr2[3,7,2]

program should retrun true because -1+3 = 2 two in arr2

```
def SumArray(arr1, arr2):
    # Write your code here
    myDictionary ={}
    ct=False
    el=arr2.pop()
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] in myDictionary:
        # print(myDictionary[arr1[i],arr1[i]])
                ct=True
                return ct

        else:
                myDictionary[el-arr1[i]]= arr1[i]
                ct=False
                return ct
```

Comment: can you paste the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Also, please fix your formatting.

Comment: What is `inputs`?

Comment: NameError: name 'inputs' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this below :

```
for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(1, len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] + arr1[j] in arr2:
            print("TRUE")
print("FALSE")
```

Comment: I second this but instead of returning booleans, rather print all-caps strings to comply with the expected outcome.

Comment: There seems to be a logical error here in the nested loop which will cause checking for the sum of the same element (except for in the first iteration). I have edited your code, do review it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using itertools:

```
import itertools
for x,y in itertools.combinations(arr1, 2):
    if x+y in arr2: 
        print("TRUE")
        break
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I tried to Edit the answer by **@Abishek Kulkarni** but was peer rejected, recommending to post it as an answer.
The said answer is not correct as it will try to sum up the current element of arr1 with itself, for the subsequent iterations after the first one.
More explanation:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(1, len(arr1)):#starting with 1 here is not sufficient to avoid
                                 #checking the self sum of the current element, 
                                 #for example when i=1 and j=1 then self sum of the element
                                 #would be checked 
        if arr1[i] + arr1[j] in arr2:
            print("TRUE")
print("FALSE")
```

Following is the fix for avoiding self sum and only check the combination of current element of arr1 with every other element of arr1 (and not with itself):

```
for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(arr1)):#i+1 Will avoid checking the same element summing it with itself
        if arr1[i] + arr1[j] in arr2:
            print("TRUE")
print("FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Blotosmetek suggested:

```
import itertools    
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [3,6]

res = any(filter(lambda x: x[0]+x[1] in arr2, itertools.combinations(arr1,2)))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might also do the trick:

```
def func(list1, list2):
    already_done = set()
    for i, augend in enumerate(list1):
        for j, addend in enumerate(list1):
            if i == j or i in already_done:
                continue
            else:
                number = augend + addend
                if number in list2:
                    return True
                else:
                    already_done.add(i)
    return False
```

You can also remove the `if i == j` part of the if statement if you accept adding twice the same number.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_sum(arr1, arr2):
     for i in range(len(arr1)):
         val = arr1.pop()
         for rem_val in arr1:
             if(val+rem_val in arr2):
                 print(val, rem_val)
                 return(True)
             else:
                 return(False)
```

Arr1 is the first array.pop() will give last value of list and remove that from list. So, now I am just running a loop to add last value to all possible and check sum to arr2.

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.